# Android action bar action color

Tags: android, android-styles

I have an application with a lot of activities, that all use the same theme:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="colorPrimary">#aaa</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

Activities all have action bar looking like by the lines of:

[image: Current action bar]

What I just can't figure out is, how to color action buttons (pencil on the right) to black.

Essentially I want to have white action bar (on screenshot is white just for action button to be visible) with black title, back arrow and action buttons, but I don't want to add `Toolbar` view to every activity I have.

So, is there a way to color action buttons black by XML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create vector icons for your menu items and set their color to black (in your case you won't need to set their color as they are black by default). To create vector asset go to `File` - `New` -`Vector Asset`.
You can also download an icon from the internet as `svg` file and import it through vector asset creating dialog.
The list of default icons is also available [here](https://design.google.com/icons/).

Comment: Oh, icons are white because they are drawables. Thanks.